# AngularJs ng-if function call from same controller not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
<div ng-repeat=" x in z"> 
    <div ng-if="function(x).y" >  
        display this
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, ng-if function(x) is not getting called without refresh.

Please check and suggest if I am missing any thing ?

Comment: Can you please provide more code (the whole ng-app and controller). Also mind that anything in a directive is not strictly JavaScript, it's an angular expression.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is working example

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.z = [1,2,3];
    $scope.display = function(x) {
        return x === 2
    };
});

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='ctrl'>
   <div ng-repeat=" x in z"> 
       <div ng-if="display(x)" >  
           display this
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JuS7W/).

Comment: I am doing exactly like this and during first call, display function does get called but after ward, once I come from some other route url, display is not called again. Any suggestions on that ?

Comment: Thank, I had another flag value that need to be checked. Working fine now.